# Adding +Quandl to Matlab path

Tags: matlab, quandl

I'm having a lot of issues with Quandl in Matlab lately.

I tried adding +urlread2 to the Matlab search path but I got the message "you cannot add method folders or private folders to the matlab search path." I don't know why I'm getting this message since I'm supposed to add +urlread2 to the path to use Quandl.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For class directories you shall only add the parent folder containing them to the path: MATLAB will then recognize the classes below automatically. This is what the message you get "means".

See for example how the genpath function is implemented.

Comment: The thing is I did that. My +urlread2 folder contains Quandl in there and I only added +urlread2 to the path. Even adding its parent directory instead, I'm still getting an error 
`Undefined variable "Quandl" or class "Quandl.auth".`